# Is Lord Shani Harmful ? OR a Friend?

Tags: gods, shani

Shani has always been one of the most feared planets in Hindu astrology. Shani sade-sati is considered highly ill-fated and all other planets fail to give any positive results if Shani is in a bad position.

Is Lord Shani Harmful OR a ‘Friend’
Who is Lord Shani? Why is Shani Dev feared? How to please Shani Dev?

Comment: His affiliation is **Deva**..so he can't be harmful..but he is a hard task master..and he punishes according to our karmas in this lifetime only..so many people might find him as too strict..

Comment: as Krishna says in Gita, if you please Bhagavan, all devas automatically get pleased.. it's like pleasing the PM of country, then u don't worry about CM

Comment: Worship of Lord Anjaneya is said to protect one from the effect of Navagrahas, it is one of his powers.

Comment: Shani is definitely not to be feared. Even Shukra, Brihaspati, Chandra also give ill fate if they are not strong in chart. Shani is just fierce in appearance so some people take advantage of it to fear others. Like, Lord Shiva is extremely dreadful in appearance, but we all know that ShriShiva is the most compassionate and benevolent. Some people even use 'BhairavaNatha' as a dreadful deity, but is Bhairava dreadful at all? No. In the same way, Shani is no harmful.

Comment: In fact, according to one school of beliefs, if you are a very good person who always does selfless good then in Saade Saati time Shani confers on you the result of your accumulated good deeds.

Comment: Learn it that Shani is Nyaayaadheesha, meaning, the Lord of Justice. So if you have been doing bad things, Shani is of course as harmful as an enemy, but if you do good things, then Shani is going to be even more benevolent than a friend.

Comment: And one thing more, do not do good in fear that Shani is going to punish you if you don't do good things. Do good things like you would normally do, without any fear or greed. Shani will take care of you.

Comment: @ram If u are implying that by worshiping Krishna one can get rid of Shani dosha in chart then that is by far from being true. Vishnu worship only pacifies a malefic mercury in one's chart. In order to pacify Shani one will have to worship Hanuman only.

Comment: Shiva is extremely dreadful in appearance-- Not true , He is by far the most handsome among all Gods.. Might be u are talking about Veerabhdra or Kalabhairava? @AnuragSingh

Comment: @Rickross I know. Shiva has been said to be "ShringaaraNayaka" - the lord of beauty. I know that Shiva has beautiful that has no second. I just meant the appearance Shiva takes(the ashes, snakes etc.). And Shiva takes up this appearance that intensify His unparalleled beauty even more. And "Dreadful" does not necessarily mean "Ugly" or  "Not beautiful".

Answer (score 2):

We find a nice description about Shani-Deva in our puranas like **Skanda Purana & Padma purana**.

Puranas tells us that Shani Deva is **sun's son.** He gained favour of **Lord Mahadeva**. And Lord Mahadeva granted him the status of planet. He is also called in puranas as "Sauri" or "Surishwara".

He is said to be a downward-look.Gods ,Asuras & humans are get affected by his look & fear him.So he is a fierce deity.

There is a story of King Dasharatha & Shani Deva. King Dasharatha composed a hymn to Shani-Deva , and Shani Deva became pleased with him.

---

How to please Shani-Deva

**Padma purana  Part 2  , chapter 52 , in the chapter  "The worship of the planets"**

> Pulastya said
>
> 20-21a : For the worship of Shanaischara (i.e. Saturn ) one should draw
>   a circle (i.e. figure) resembling a human figure with black powders
>   and there should devoutly worship the planet with black sandle , black
>   flowers , pieces of cloth of that kind (black).
>
> 21b-22 : Iron and other gifts should be given also oil cakes &
>   sesamums. The present for shani being unfavorable is black cow and a
>   black garment.One should also give according to one's capacity gold
>   and sapphire.
>
> 23 : One should recite the hymn - O sun's son , O glorious one ,O you
>   very mighty one , O you having downward look , O shani be pleased by
>   means of  these presents made by me.
>
> 24 : He who having thus devoutly pleased shani ,would give presents to
>   Brahmanas has shani favourable to him.If he was unfavourable at his
>   birth and passing to other zodiacal sign.

---

This is what Skanda-Purana says -:

**Skanda Purana ,Book 7  - PRABHASA KANDA , Chapter 49 , "Sanaicaresvara"**

> 4 : The lord without beginning or death was bought down to the linga by
>   him.Due to his devotion to shambhu he gained his favour & status of
>   planet.
>
> 5-7 : The great community of devas and asuras is afraid of his adverse
>   look.In whole of the cosmos consisting of mobile & immobile beings
>   ,there is no living being ,Deva or Danava who is not affected by sauri
>   (saturn).
>
> The devotee should worship saureshwara shiva with  devoutly on
>   saturdays with sami leaves and rice cooked with gingerly seeds , black
>   gram and jaggery.After offering libations according to injections ,he
>   should offer a black bull to Brahmanas.

---

It was Shani who was said to have burnt off  head of
[**Ganesha**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hmvp/hmvp42.htm)

---

> नीलांजन समाभासम रवि पुत्रम यमाग्रजं ।
>  छाया मार्तान्ड समभुतम तं
>   नमामि शनैश्चरम ।।
>
> NILANJANA SAMABHASAM RAVI PUTRAM YAMAGRAJAM | CHAYA MARTHANDA
>   SAMBHUTAM TAM NAMAMI SHANAISCHARAM ||
>
> Meaning- Oh god dressed in blue silk, who has a blue body, Who wears a
>   crown, who sits on vulture, Who gives misfortunes, who is armed with a
>   bow, Who has four hands and who is son of Sun God, Be pleased with me
>   always and happily grant me boons.
>   [image]
>
> ---
>
> [image]